# htaccess php redirect between php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How can redirect the url from A to B as below:

A: abcedf.com/w/index.php?fulltext=Search&search=**hong+kong**
B: www.abcedf.com/en/wiki.php?word=**hong+kong**

I tried to use the below code but not work

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abcedf.com/w/index.php?fulltext=Search&search=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcedf.com/en/wiki.php?word=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Try this link http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php to generate the htaccess code for redirection. This may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to select the `search` GET parameter:

```
# existing .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abcedf.com/w/index.php?fulltext=Search&search=$ [NC]

# new Cond and Rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)search=(.*?)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcedf.com/en/wiki.php?word=%2 [L,R=301]
```

This will remain working if you're going to change your GET parameters on `index.php` (as long as you don't rename `search`).

e.g:

```
# changing the parameter order
abcedf.com/w/index.php?search=hong+kong&fulltext=Search

# adding other parameters
abcedf.com/w/index.php?fulltext=Search&search=hong+kong&test=asdf&test=abcedf
```